# AngularJS promise not resolving file with FileReader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am trying to write a very simple function in my service that will create a FileReader, read the small image file I send it and return this result in a promise to my controller. The file gets to my service just fine. It gets to my controller and logs just a blank line. I assume I am messing up the promise part of this somehow. Where am I going wrong there?

Service funtion --

```
this.fileRead  = function(file) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    deferred.resolve(reader.result);

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Controller function --

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
     MyService.fileRead($files[0])
                  .then(function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                 });
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have no onload event, so it doesn't actually return the read file data.

```
this.fileRead  = function(file) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function() {
        deferred.resolve(reader.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: exactly what I was missing. was now able to create a small image preview piece with this. thanks!

Comment: @CoreyMichaelCochran This answer seems to have helped you. You should mark it as helpful by clicking the arrow to the left (it will turn green if you have done this properly). Voting (up/down) helps sort out what community finds to be the best answer, "accepting" an answer tells people which answer helped you the most. Both are good to do!

Comment: I had already thought I did that. Sorry for the late response. Thanks again.

Comment: this is the best solution i found in the web